# Image inside a div, always comes out a few pixels underneath

Tags: html, css, sass, tailwind-css

[Here is my example to test](https://codepen.io/funnyfrontend/pen/ExdyMxO)

Hi, I am trying to simulate a skelleton by adding a grey background (**shine-me** class) to the **div** that surrounds all my web images.

```
 <div class="shine-me">
    <img src="https://r.rp-static.com/r/cms/banners/942927fd271ce6e95646e1c2e9b7ab8d/1000/mobile.webp?lang=es" class="tw-img mx-auto" alt="dsfsdf" title="sdfsdf">
  </div>
```

The problem is that this div with the grey skelleton background protrudes below the image a few pixels... leaving a horrible grey line.

I don't understand why this happens, since both image and div should adapt to the same size (the size of the image at that moment).

I don't want to solve it by adding a fixed height because it is impossible to cover all mobile devices.

Can someone tell me why I get that annoying gray line? Thank you very much

Comment: Try `img{ display: block }`